# htaccess behavior when accessing root

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I've been using this htaccess code to pass on vars to redirect.php which handles the includes for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ redirect.php?value1=$1&value2=$2&value3=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)$ redirect.php?value1=$1&value2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ redirect.php?value1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but i noticed that it will not go to redirect if all arguments is empty, so if i go to http://domain.com/ it will open index.php, but if i go to http://domain.com/any-param/ redirect.php handles it correctlty. How can I make it always use redirect.php as default, even when no additional URL parameters is set?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/$ redirect.php?value1=%2F` with no `RewriteCond`s?

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteBase /` in there? It may be required for this...

Comment: Didn't make any diffrence. I'm starting to loose it.. like wth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules appear to be fine to me. Just add this line in the end:

```
RewriteRule ^$ redirect.php [L]
```

This will redirect `http://domain.com/` to `http://domain.com/redirect.php`.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it was easy but glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

use to do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]+)?/?([a-z]+)?/?([-a-z0-9]+)?/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?([a-z]+)?/?([-a-z0-9]+)?/?$ /redirect.php?value1=$1&value2=$2&value3=$3 [NC,L]
```

Note: Even with only 1 param, this will still work as it just leaves the other 2 blank. So you don't have to copy and paste thew same code while removing just one condition.

I found that this is not very scalable. Now I just redirect everything to the index.php and let that file fetch and dissect the URI to handle my system layout. This allows for a very scalable system.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's old code. I now tried both your suggestion and also one that sends _everything_ to redirect.php. But none of them work!  Is this becasue I have another similar htaccess in the parent directory? The site is runned as a subdomain, so I didn't think it would be an issue... Also, the new htaccess should overwrite anything in the parent dir, right? :s
Anyway, it doesn't seem to matter what I'm trying, unless there's parameters after the domain, it will always try index.php or show directory listing if I rename index. What could be wrong?

Comment: Ruled out the other htaccess/use of subdomain as issue by removing it temporarily, no change. No matter what, it always tries index.php first if no argument. If this shit continues, I'll have to rearrange my code and simply use index.php for the redirect.php functionality after all - even thought I'd feel beaten.. :(